# @Validated not taken into account

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a pretty simple REST service set up, and was starting to validate it using Bean validation. Everything worked fine, until I noticed I needed different Validations on the same object for different methods.

I tried group Validation.
My problem is, when I replace my functionning @Valid annotations with @Validated(Group.class) annotations, no more validation is done.

Here are my objects and configuration files:

End point:

```
 <jaxrs:server id="myRestServices" address="/v1">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="rentalsService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="validationInInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="validationProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider" />
<bean id="validationInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor">
     <property name="provider" ref="validationProvider" />
</bean>
```

Service:

```
public interface RentalsService {

public Rental createRental(@Validated({ CreateValidationGroup.class }) Rental rental);

public Rental updateRental(String RentalId, @Validated({ UpdateValidationGroup.class }) Rental rental);
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Path("/rentals")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RentalServiceImpl implements RentalsService {

private RentalBusinessService rentalBusinessService;

@POST
@Override
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Rental createRental(@Validated({ CreateValidationGroup.class }) Rental rental) {
    return rentalBusinessService.createRental(rental);
}

@PUT
@Override
@Path("/{RentalId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Rental updateRental(@PathParam("RentalId") String RentalId, @Validated({ UpdateValidationGroup.class }) Rental rental) {
    return rentalBusinessService.updateRental(RentalId, rental);
}
```

`
Said groups:

```
    public interface CreateValidationGroup {

}  public interface UpdateValidationGroup {

}
```

And finally the Object:

```
public class Rental {   

@Size(min = 2, max = 14, groups = { UpdateValidationGroup.class }, message = " 2 < Status < 4 ") 
private String status;


@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 14, message = " 2 < Product < 4 ")
private String product;

@Size(min = 2, max = 14, groups = { CreateValidationGroup.class }, message = " 2 < ID < 4 ")
private String RentalId;
```

Can i not use Group Validation this way? Switching the @Validated back to @Valid triggers validation.

Comment: We have used group validation only in web layer .. not sure if it can be done in the service layer. When we did this in web layer it was similar to what you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and did it mannually:

Injected a Smartvalidator, and called the validate method on my object while specifying the group. Which is what I was trying to avoid...

```
private SmartValidator validator;

private RentalBusinessService rentalBusinessService;

@POST
@Override
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Rental createRental(Rental rental) {

    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(rental, "rental");
    validator.validate(rental, errors, CreateValidationGroup.class);

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
       //dostuff
    }
```

And the injected bean:

```
<bean id="smartValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

If anyone knows how to do this via annotations, i'd still like to know where I went wrong.